# Haraka : exclude some receiver domains

Tags: email, smtp, haraka

I'm configuring my first mail server in Haraka and i'm asking me if it's possible to exclude some receiver domains. I imagine something like that :

In my file "excludedomain", i have a list of domains that i want to exclude : `first.com;second.com`

If i send mail to first@first.com and third@third.com, only the "third" mail address receive it.

I didn't found informations about that on the official website of Haraka. It's possible to implement this with Haraka mail server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at Haraka access [ACL](https://haraka.github.io/manual/plugins/access.html).

> This plugin applies Access Control Lists during the connect, helo, mail, and rcpt phases of the SMTP conversation.